# Preloading page like youtube

Tags: html, preloading

I am surprised by the display system of Youtube. When we are on the main page  https://www.youtube.com/ and we click on one link of the menu at the left side to go to this page for example https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending, there is no flashing when going from one page to another.

It looks like the new page is preloaded and then display only the difference with the page before. 
Furthermore there is the progress bar system (like this one  http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/) which ends all the time at 60% on the current page, then starts at 60% on the new page and go straight to 100%.

Any clue how they do that? Javascript, specific server configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of frameworks like Angular or React, as a single page app (SPA), which use data APIs to load data and two-way binding to dynamically update only the things that have changed.

Comment: I am using jQuery - Bootstrap with Apache - PHP on server side. Any chance to do it with these technologies ?

Comment: You can... but I'd highly recommend something like Angular, React, Meteor, or any of the other. There is a LOT of logic required to build this yourself. If it is an existing site, React is probably your best bet. It's the easiest to drop on top of an existing site, though it'll still be quite a bit of work. It's usually easier to start from scratch for a SPA then try to retrofit an existing site. Luckily, all of those I just mentioned are written in JavaScript, can work with a PHP backend, and also mesh well with Bootstrap. It's pretty much just jQuery you'd be swapping out.